# xcode 5 tabulate in UITextView

Tags: objective-c, tabs, uitextview

Im trying to show score table in the game. Im using \t for alignment in UITextView. But when nickname is longer than some others score text is moving right:

Here's screenshot:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PXhG.png

This is my code:

```
final = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@\n\t%@\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t\t%@ очков", final, nick, score];
```

How can i get scores started at one X-coordinate?

Comment: I will suggest you to use the table view instead of TextView.

Comment: But it's require much more code. May be there a small mistake in my code?